# Mongodb Query in Shiny R to fetch the data from the database using reactive input

Tags: r, mongodb, shiny

```
library(shiny)
library(mongolite)

ui <- fluidPage( 
    titlePanel("Mongodb Data"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
             textInput("_id", "Document type:", "")
        ),
        mainPanel(
            dataTableOutput("mydata")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    mon <- mongo(collection = "collectionname", db = "db name", url = "mongodb://localhost:27017")
    output$mydata <- renderDataTable({
        doc_type <- paste0(doc_type= input$doc_id)

        mon$find(  query = '{"doc_type" : {"$in" : ["x", "y"]} }' , limit = 100) 
    })
}
}
```

> Warning: The Error, Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)

How to add a reactive query and retrieve data from a particular column from MongoDB collection? whenever I give text input value x or y it should show relevant documents from MongoDB database.

Comment: You have `textInput("_id",...)` but then have `input$doc_id`. Is that a typo that "_id" is not the same as "doc_id"?

Comment: yes, it is a typo error. I'm sorry for the mistake. @MrFlick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a query that changes according to user input. Try changing your server code to this. I'm considering there's a typo in your question and your actual input is this `textInput("doc_id", "Document type:", "")`

Server:

```
  mon <- mongo(collection = "collectionname", db = "db name", url = "mongodb://localhost:27017")

  # Create a reactive element. Changes when the user input changes
  data.for.table <- reactive({
    # Build a query that concatenates value of input$doc_id to other strings
    query.foo <- paste0('{"doc_type" : {"', input$doc_id, '" : ["x", "y"]} }' )
    # Retrieve data
    mon$find(query = query.foo, limit = 100)
  })

  output$mydata <- renderDataTable({
    data.for.table()
  })
```

Comment: I tried using the above code. it throws an error : (Warning: Error in: Invalid filter: empty key)  @ Vishesh Srivastav

Comment: the above code works for selectInput() but not textInput()